# Tomcat uses stack intsead of queue?Why it is better use stack instead of queue or anyother pool?

Tags: java, tomcat, concurrency

While I was reading through the [Tomcat source code](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint.java#L187), I found that a stack is being used for processor object caching. Why should a `SynchronizedStack` be preferred over e.g. `ConcurentLinkedQueue`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference that data structure to use for free processors, while it allows item to be added, and available item to be selected in constant time. But linked code is concurrent, and there is a way easier and effective to implement concurrent stack than concurrent queue.

The javadoc for [SynchronizedStack](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/collections/SynchronizedStack.java) explicitly says:

> This is intended as a (mostly) GC-free alternative to
>    `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` when the requirement is to
>    create a pool of re-usable objects with no requirement to shrink the pool.
>    The aim is to provide the bare minimum of required functionality as quickly
>    as possible with minimum garbage.

Comment: Hmm but still why since they have already implemented [SynchronizedQueue](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/collections/SynchronizedQueue.java), also  ConcurrentLinkedQueue is wait free algorithm. whereas SynchronizedStack & SynchronizedQueue is blocking

Comment: Let's compare `SynchronizedStack.push` and `SynchronizedStack.offer` in the stable case, i.e. neither stack or queue will be expanded any further. In this case, `push` executes increment, comparison (correctly predicted to be `false`), array store and return. `offer` executes increment, array store, comparison (sometimes incorrectly predicted as `false`), another comparison (correctly predicted to be `false`), return. Thus, `offer` costs one (sometimes incorrectly predicted) comparison more. The same analysis hold for `pop` and `poll` methods.